# Automatically add new posts to the Sidebar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, netlify, vuepress, netlify-cms

I'm using [VuePress](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/) and [NetlifyCMS](https://www.netlifycms.org/) as Content Management.

I have 3 collections (**design**, **front-end** and **back-end**) which contains an indefinite number of pages. Those pages are created through the **NetlifyCMS dashboard** and are added to the defined folder.

- New design pages are added to the **design** folder.
- New front-end pages are added to the **front-end** folder.
- [...]

This works fine but I'm facing an issue.
Since my new pages are not defined in the sidebar config, they are not available from the sidebar interface. How could I do that while keeping the same sidebar format as below?

**config.js**

```vue
[...],
sidebar: {
  '/design/': [{
    title: 'Design',
    children: [
      '',
      'foo 1',
      'foo 2'
    ]
  }],
  '/front-end/': [{
    title: 'Front-end',
    children: [
      '',
      'bar 1',
      'bar 2'
    ]
  }],
  '/back-end/': [{
    title: 'Back-end',
    children: [
      '',
      'baz 1',
      'baz 2'
    ]
  }]
},
[...]
```

---

**config.yml**

```yml
[...],
collections:
  - name: "design"
    label: "Design"
    folder: "docs/design"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
  - name: "front-end"
    label: "Front-end"
    folder: "docs/front-end"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
  - name: "back-end"
    label: "Back-end"
    folder: "docs/back-end"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to import your filenames into the config at build.

Add a script to your `docs/.vuepress` folder:

`docs/.vuepress/childscript.js`

```js
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function(path) {
  var files = fs.readdirSync(path);
  var list = [""];
  for (var i in files) {
    var filename = files[i].split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.');
    if (filename.toLowerCase() !=="readme") list.push(filename);
  }
  console.log(`${path}: `, list);
  return list;
}
```

Then change your `docs/.vuepress/config.js`

```js
var getChildren = require('./childscript');

[...],
sidebar: {
  '/design/': [{
    title: 'Design',
    children: getChildren('./docs/design/')
  }],
  '/front-end/': [{
    title: 'Front-end',
    children: getChildren('./docs/front-end/')
  }],
  '/back-end/': [{
    title: 'Back-end',
    children: getChildren('./docs/back-end/')
  }]
},
[...]
```

***NOTE:*** The caveat here is the sort order of the filenames during the reading of the directory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if there is any way to proceed with a publish date order?

Comment: Did the answer not work for you? As far as date order, maybe [changing your slug](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#slug) to {{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}} in the collection would work.

Comment: Otherwise, you will have to store the publish date (or sort value) in the frontmatter and do a readfile on each and convert the contents using a markdown tool and do your sorts based on the value.

Comment: Yeah that would work but the slug would be too long. I was thinking about a way to create a `number field` named **order**, then inject its value before the `{{slug}}` template.

Comment: Hi @talves, Are you using NetlifyCMS only or it's deploying on Netlify as well? If you don't mind, can you help me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55564958/is-it-possible-to-use-the-netlify-cms-only-with-vuepress-but-without-deploying-o