# Is it possible to add pages to a Vuepress site through Netlify CMS back-end dynamically?

Tags: vue.js, netlify, vuepress, netlify-cms

I'm trying to add pages to a Vuepress site I created with a Netlify CMS back-end. It seems the only way is to add them statically:

```
    sidebar: [
      '/welcome',
      '/test'
    ],
```

I assume there must be a way for pages to auto-populate when ever you create a new page in Netlify CMS.

I have already tried [Automatically add new posts to the Sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262091/automatically-add-new-posts-to-the-sidebar) but with no luck. I imagine there must be a simpler solution, as adding pages dynamically through a CMS is kind of the whole point of implementing a CMS back-end.

Comment: Haven't used VuePress yet, but if you can configure that sidebar array in a static data file (json, yaml, toml), the CMS could edit it.

Comment: Yes, It's possible. Check it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262091/automatically-add-new-posts-to-the-sidebar